# How to assign Numpy array values to other variable

Tags: python, numpy

This is my code:

```
y_predForThisMatchType = model.predict(X_test, num_iteration=model.best_iteration)
print(type(y_predForThisMatchType))
y_predForThisMatchType = y_predForThisMatchType.reshape(-1)
print(type(y_predForThisMatchType))

count = 0
for i in range (len(y_pred)):
    if y_pred.loc[i]  == abType:
        y_pred.loc[i] = y_predForThisMatchType[count]
        count = count + 1
```

Output:

> class 'numpy.ndarray'
>
> class 'numpy.ndarray'
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:189: SettingWithCopyWarning:
>
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
> self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)

Python just print the above output, and that's all. The program is technically running, but below code do not get executed, no real error is shown.

Error Line:
`y_pred.loc[i] = y_predForThisMatchType[count]`

`y_pred` variable is a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your outputs completely?
In my experience, your code is working.
The display is just a warning and can be disabled with:

```
pandas.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
```

Comment: Yes, I have checked everything.

Comment: `count = count + 1` Are you sure your count increment should be inside the `if` then? Or should it be 1 level out?

Comment: Yeah, I am sure. It should be inside `If`

Comment: @John Doe I'm unable to discern more given the current information then, sorry

Comment: Something come up, I need to go out now. I will update this question, so it can be reproduced, and notify you.